# Replace specific character from all columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, stringi

Having a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), date1 = c("Nov 2016 <U+2192> Current", "Nov 2016 <U+2192> Current"), date2 = c("Nov 2016 <U+2192> Current", "Nov 2016 <U+2192> Current"))
```

Is there any command to replace this character in the whole dataframe?

Example:

```
df <- gsub(' <U+2192> ', '-', df)
```

Comment: `df$date1 <- gsub(' <U+2192> ', '-', df$date1)`?

Comment: @PanagiotisTogias for the whole dataframe not for one column

Comment: with `dplyr` : `df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ gsub(' <U+2192> ', '-', ., fixed = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

Placing it here also as an answer:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ gsub(' <U+2192> ', '-', ., fixed = TRUE)))
```

Output

```
  id            date1            date2
1  1 Nov 2016-Current Nov 2016-Current
2  2 Nov 2016-Current Nov 2016-Current
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution with `sapply`:

```
df <- sapply(df, function(x) gsub(" <U\\+2192>", " -", x))
```

Note that `+` must be escaped unless you use the `fixed = TRUE` argument

```
df
     id  date1                date2               
[1,] "1" "Nov 2016 - Current" "Nov 2016 - Current"
[2,] "2" "Nov 2016 - Current" "Nov 2016 - Current"
```